# Need help identifying some sets

Tags: sets

[image]

So I have a few LEGO sets that I bought at a garage sale. They didn't come with an instruction manual or anything but they are from 2011 and one of them has a white box that says 6049732 on it. Can anyone help me identify these sets or where I can go to identify them? Thanks. This is the first set.

Comment: Welcome Hunter Jin! Quick clarification: That number "6049732" and the year "2011" are not related to the set - they are the identification numbers of the plastic bag itself. All you can deduct from those is that the set was made in 2011 or later (and in this case, had at least 2 bags).

Answer (score 3):

I think you have bag #2 from this set: [60022 Cargo Terminal](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60022-1), based on the tan 4x6 base plates, the black 2x2 round plate with 4 arms and the red City minifig cap. I've also cross-checked the rim piece, the 2x3 Red plate and the 2x4 yellow brick.[image]